# int to char C++ help me

Tags: c++

it isn't working,
i need keep many files but with different names,
for example:
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
where the numbers are the counter, and it counter
be X.

Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>


using namespace std;
using std::string;


string ItoStr (int x);

int main(){

   string cadena;
   int x = 1;
   ofstream fs("nombre" + ItoStr(x) + ".txt"); //Fail line
   fs << cadena;
   fs << cadena;
   fs.close();


    };


string ItoStr (int x){

    string str2;
    stringstream ss;
    ss << x;
    str2 = ss.str();
    return str2;

    };
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  If you want someone to take time  to help you, please spend a little time crafting a usable question.  See these links - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask  and http://sscce.org/  What does "is not working" mean?  We are not mind readers.  If you don't provide ALL relevant details, we can't help you.

Comment: I suggest `std::to_string`. However, that won't work pre-C++11, which I presume you're using since a `std::string` won't work for the constructor. In that case, `boost::lexical_cast`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to break it up, and change:

```
ofstream fs("nombre" + ItoStr(x) + ".txt");
```

to:

```
string fname = "nombre" + ItoStr(x) + ".txt";
ofstream fs(fname.c_str());
```

The problem is that `ofstream`s constructor takes (in C++98, which you seem to be using) a `const char *`, but you're creating a (temporary) `std::string`.

Comment: there are a few constructors among which is [`explicit ofstream (const string& filename, ios_base::openmode mode = ios_base::out);`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/ofstream/)

Comment: @PeterT: Edited for clarity.